# How do you implement a process driven by content state?

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I would like to enforce a task transition (activiti `sequenceFlow`) only to be possible if the content of the package in the workflow fulfills certain requirements. The basic scenario is that I want users to manually set a custom invoice date on all items of the package before we allow the task ("assign dates") to transition (and the process to terminate). Hence, I need to check whether all items have been processed. Alfresco Share serves as the UI.

At first sight, it seems what I want is a `conditionExpression` on the sequenceFlow. I am note quite sure when this gets evaluated, but I guess it will be after user interaction which would be to late.

If this is not possible using default mechanics, maybe this requirement should be addressed  by implementing a custom task form or repository form processor tweaks.

What is a reasonable technical solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You should post your workflow code, so we could provide a better solution. Anyway, the best way is to implement a piece of javascript inside your Activiti (hope you're using Activiti BPMN) task that changes a custom property associated with the bpm package (node) and then use the condition expression to check the property value and execute transition.
example:

```
        <userTask id="activitiApprove" name="Document approve" activiti:assignee="${bpm_assignee.properties.userName}" activiti:formKey="wfstu:activitiApprove">
          <extensionElements>
            <activiti:taskListener event="create" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
              <activiti:field name="script">
                <activiti:string>if (typeof bpm_workflowDueDate != 'undefined') task.setVariableLocal('bpm_dueDate', bpm_workflowDueDate);
                            if (typeof bpm_workflowPriority != 'undefined') task.priority = bpm_workflowPriority;
    for (var i = 0; i &amp;lt; bpm_package.children.length; i++) {
        var doc = bpm_package.children[i];
        doc.properties['stu:customProperty']= "UPLOADED";
        doc.save();
    }
    logger.log("My Workflow - Transition from start to activitiApprove");</activiti:string>
              </activiti:field>
            </activiti:taskListener>
            <activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
              <activiti:field name="script">
                <activiti:string>execution.setVariable('wfstu_approveReject', task.getVariable('wfstu_approveReject'))
wfstu_approveReject = "OK";</activiti:string>
              </activiti:field>
            </activiti:taskListener>
          </extensionElements>
        </userTask>
        <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="activitiApprove" targetRef="decisionApprove"></sequenceFlow>
        <exclusiveGateway id="decisionApprove" name="Approve decision"></exclusiveGateway>
        <sequenceFlow id="flow3" sourceRef="decisionApprove" targetRef="approve">
          <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${wfstu_approveReject == 'OK'}]]></conditionExpression>
        </sequenceFlow>
        <sequenceFlow id="flow4" sourceRef="decisioneApprovazione" targetRef="reject">
          <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${wfstu_approveReject == 'KO'}]]></conditionExpression>
        </sequenceFlow>
```

Or something similar to this.

Comment: I guess that won't work, because the state of content may still change after activiti (task-)listeners kick in and set the value based on content state at that time. Assume a user changes content metadata after the listener executed. Setting the process variable on complete seems to late and semantically wrong when logically, you do not want the task to complete unless the content fulfills certain requirements.

Comment: Well you could change the event on "complete"  to be on "start" or "change", not really sure what are all of the values allowed for the event tag... Anyhow.. You should hide the property that is used by the workflow from the user.. So he shouldn't be able to change it.. And the state of the content is never going to change. I was just showing a reasonable technical solution.  We use the same code and it works like a charm. We have the state property selection "disabled"  in our workflow form and the user can't modify it..

Comment: Actually I need content state to change before the user-task ("Assign Invoice Dates" in my scenario) finishes. Hence, I would like to disallow the sequenceFlow at the process-level if requirements are not fulfilled.

Comment: Ok, but the content state is an automatic change? Could you provide a full example of the sequence you want to obtain?

Comment: Added the logical process description.